# What order does maven find its dependencies?

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I've got a multi module project that uses [war overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) and we have a continuous integration server that often deploys the snapshots.  I have questions like, if I do a `mvn compile` right after the CI server does a deploy of it, will my build get my local changes or the CI changes?  How do I force my project to use a war overlay I've changed locally?  I figure an `install` could do that, but what if the CI server builds a version with a newer timestamp.  Which one will it use?

This is just a few of the many questions I have and I can't find an authoritative answer on the maven documentation.  But, even if I could I'd probably come right back here and ask someone to explain the documentation better :P  So, I ask, what is the order/logic maven uses to find it's dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as Maven concerns, the artifact generated from your war overlays will just be yet another artifact.

> if I do a mvn compile right after the CI server does a deploy of it, will my build get my local changes or the CI changes?

This will be depending on your snapshots updatePolicy in your settings file. It is by default set to *daily*. More details here: http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories

> How do I force my project to use a war overlay I've changed locally?

Change the snapshots updatePolicy to *never* (or -o option, suggested by @matsev). This means the SNAPSHOT dependencies that you are using will always be the local version. To *force* grab the latest from the repository one with this updatePolicy, use the -U option.

> I figure an install could do that, but what if the CI server builds a version with a newer timestamp. Which one will it use?

Yes, **install** will basically deploy your artifact to your local repository (.m2 folder). Then, depending on the updatePolicy, maven will compare the locally deployed artifact and the repository artifact. If updatePolicy is set to *always*, maven will *always* grab the repository one **if** it has a newer timestamp. The same goes to *daily*, except that maven will only compare the timestamp *daily*.

> I can't find an authoritative answer on the maven documentation.

Totally agree. Sadly, I understand most of these partly through experience.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying that I'll get the `module` from the CI server instead of my local environment if the updatePolicy is `always` and the CI has a newer version?  Just want to make sure that `modules` act the same way as `dependencies` in this way.  Because if maven `always` used the local version of `modules`, that's probably be better behavior.

Comment: Please answer that question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073441/in-maven-do-modules-respect-the-repositorys-updatepolicy  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-o` (`--offline`) option to force Maven to use your local files, e.g.

```
mvn -o clean install
```

See [Maven Command Line Options](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-help-option) for reference (or simply execute `mvn -h`).

Comment: That is helpful information and I'll probably use that in the future.  But it's not a direct answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

e know that a project's dependencies are declared in pom.xml. Apache Maven uses concept of repository to hold JAR files. There are two kinds of repository, local repository and remote repository. You can define this in settings.xml on maven/conf directory or pom.xml itself. When we kick off Maven build process by executing mvn install command, it first search for dependency JAR in local repository, if it found there it uses, otherwise it goes to remote repository to download corresponding version of JAR file and stores into local repo as well. There is one more thing, which is worth remember is type of dependency. If you have included a SNAPSHOT JAR e.g. 1.2-SNAPSOT as part of your dependency, opposite to regular stable version 1.2