# In Maven, do modules get effected by the repository's updatePolicy?

Tags: java, maven

[This is just like this other question I asked, but instead of dependencies, this is about modules.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049895/what-order-does-maven-find-its-dependencies)  Let me give a scenario.  You've got a multi-`module` project and a continuous integration server that deploys the project.  This deploys to a repository that your local `settings.xml` has an `updatePolicy` of `always`.  Now imagine you run `mvn compile` right after the CI deploys the project.

**Will you end up compiling against the remote server's `modules`, or your local modules?**

In other words, does the `updatePolicy` of a repository have any effect on the `module` tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`modules` tag is an aggregation. It is not treated the same as `dependencies`. Notice that the value that you specify in `dependency` and `module` is different. When you declare a `dependency`, you specify [maven coordinates](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/simple-project-sect-simple-core.html). Whilst for `module`, you specify [relative directories](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation).

> Will you end up compiling against the remote server's modules, or your local modules?

You will always end up compiling against your local module **if** you run the `mvn compile` in the aggregator module (NOT in the child module!) **and** the child module dependency is a sibling dependency. When you `mvn compile` in an aggregator module, the dependency lookup when it is compiling the child module will be special. It will look from the sibling modules target folder **ONLY**. I can't find documentation on this, but you can try it out.

Imagine that you have these aggregator pom

```
...
<modules>
  <module>child-a</module>
  <module>child-b</module>
</modules>
....
```

child-b pom is declaring a dependency against child-a. (Make sure you have a real output classes)

Next, when you `mvn compile` the aggregator pom, child-b will be able to compile even if you have NOT `mvn install` child-a before. That means, child-a is not even in your local repository. This is possible because maven will look into child-a's target folder for the classes. To confirm this, you can try to run `mvn compile clean` (yes, clean after compile).

Again, do note that this behavior only applies when you run it from the aggregator pom. If your current working directory is child-b (which is dependent on child-a), it will respect the updatePolicy when it tries to look for child-a.

Comment: For the point about `the dependency lookup when it is compiling the child module will be special. It will look from the sibling modules target folder ONLY`.  I believe Maven always try to resolve dependencies within the reactor first.  It will only lookup from repo if such dependency is not available in reactor.  I am not sure if it is explicitly described in doc (I believe so) but it is also straight forward because it will be a mess if it doesn't work like that, when I am simply doing `mvn compile`.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the current behaviour for `mvn compile`. What you said it's correct for `mvn install`. To further confirm this, we can try to run them with -X for both commands. `mvn compile` classpath in -X is: child-b\target\classes, child-a\target\classes. `mvn install` classpath in -X is: child-b\target\classes, .m2\child-a\1.0-SNAPSHOT\child-a-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. I'm guessing that maven can't assume that the child-a.jar will be in any repository if you use `compile`, so it is ussing the child-a\target\classes instead.

Comment: I'd rather think the opposite way: Because you are using install, therefore Maven knows the dependencies will be installed to local repo even if it is a module in current project.  That make it works fine to point to the JAR in local repo.  For compile, because dependency (which is a module in current project) is not going to be installed in local repo, in order to build with correct dependency, Maven put the output directory of that module in reactor.

Comment: Yeap. That's what I meant, see the -X output. Voted up as it made things clearer.